# SQL Join 2 tables

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables one named `Person`, which contains columns `ID` and `Name` and the second one, named `Relation`, which contains two columns, each of which contains an `ID` of a `Person`. It's about a relation between customer and serviceman. I'd like to Join these two tables so that I'll have names of people in every relation. Is it possible to write this query with some kind of joining?

EDIT::

I must do something wrong, but it's not working. I had tried a lot of forms of so looking queries, but I had been only getting one column or some errors. It's actually the school task, I have it already done (with different JOIN query). Firstly I had been trying to do this, but I'd failed: It seems to be very common situation, so I don't know why it's too complicated for me..

Here are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Oprava..(Repair) (  
  KodPodvozku INTEGER PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES Automobil(KodPodvozku),  
  IDzakaznika..(IDcustomer) INTEGER REFERENCES Osoba(ID),  
  IDzamestnance..(IDemployee) INTEGER REFERENCES Osoba(ID)  
);

CREATE TABLE Osoba..(Person) (  
  ID INTEGER CONSTRAINT primaryKeyOsoba PRIMARY KEY ,  
  Jmeno..(Name) VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,  
  OP INTEGER UNIQUE NOT NULL  
);
```

It's in Czech, but the words in brackets after ".." are english equivalents.
PS: I am using Oracle SQL.

Comment: When you have a correct answer, please remember to accept it. It is important in our community.

Comment: check out this article, it should help:  www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/Understanding-SQL-Joins/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your tables are:

```
persons:   (id, name)
relations: (customer_id, serviceman_id)
```

Using standard SQL:

```
SELECT p1.name AS customer_name, 
       p2.name AS serviceman_name
FROM persons p1 
     JOIN relations ON p1.id=relations.customer_id
     JOIN persons p2 ON relations.serviceman_d=p2.id;
```

#### Further explanation

The join creates the following table:

```
p1.id|p1.name|relations.customer_id|relations.serviceman_id|p2.id|p2.name
```

Where `p1.id=relations.customer_id`, and `p2.id=relations.serviceman_id`. The `SELECT` clause chooses only the names from the `JOIN`.

Note that if all the ids from `relations` are also in `persons`, the result size would be exactly the size of the `relations` table. You might want to add a [foreign key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) to verify that.

Comment: My answer still stands, match your table and column names to mine.

Comment: I maked so, there might be mistake somewhere else. I'll take a closer look at it:D

Comment: So you were right..It was another dummy mistake from..We are working in SQL Developer. There when you are looking on your output and if it's for example VARCHAR(128), you get a 128 chars long word, doesn't matter how long it real is..It's bit confusing..Actually since beginning of my attempts I got manytimes right output, but I didn't see it:DSo I appreciate your answer, many thanks and I'm going to smash my head against the wall:)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM Relation
INNER JOIN Person P1
ON P1.ID = Relation.FirstPersonID
INNER JOIN Person P2
ON P2.ID = Relation.SecondPersonID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p1.name AS customer, p2.name AS serciveman
FROM person p1, person p2, relation
WHERE p1.id=relation.customerid AND p2.id=relation.servicemanid
```

Comment: Yes..It's working, but I have to (at this time actually want to) use JOIN for it..I have edited my question, there you can see, why JOIN:)Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Person(ID, Name)
Relation(ID)

You don't mention the other columns that relation contains but this is what you need:

```
Select name
from Person as p
join Relation as r
on p.ID = r.ID
```

This is an [INNER JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) as are most of the other answers here.  Please don't use this until you understand that if either record doesn't have a relationship in the other table it will be missing from the dataset (i.e. you can lose data)

Its very important to understand the [different types of join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) so I would use this as an opportunity.