# How can I join two SQL tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this

```
pulseid | RunID | Name | Value |<br>
  1     |   1   | api  | 0     |<br>
  2     |   1   | api  | 0     |<br>
  3     |   1   | api  | 0     |<br>

pulseid | RunID | Name | Value |<br>
  1     |   1   | rot  | 900   |<br>
  2     |   1   | rot  | 10    |<br>
  3     |   1   | rot  | 35    |<br>
```

PulseId is the common  field between two tables. I would like a script which will give me a result like so

```
pulseid | Rot   | API  | Value |<br>
  1     |   900 | 0    | 900   |<br>
  2     |   10  | 0    | 10    |<br>
  3     |   35  | 0    | 35    |<br>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why the downvotes?  Joining two SQL tables seems like useful knowledge to anybody.

Comment: A simple search of stackOverflow will answer this for you.  I'm sure you were presented with several good options when you wrote the question.  Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313196/sql-join-2-tables

Comment: @BarbaraLaird if you read the question closely you'll see that the actual output is not just a simple join.  It's more like a pivot.

Comment: @StephenD 1. no efforts. 2. This question is asked every 10 minutes on [SO]. 3. unclear specification of expected output (too few data). The [FAQ] clearly details on what questions are welcome, and in what format....

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a `PIVOT`.  With just two columns it's probably easier to simulate it with a `UNION` and a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT 
    pulseid, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Name = 'rot' THEN Value ELSE 0 END) Rot,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Name = 'API' THEN Value ELSE 0 END) API
FROM {tablename}
GROUP BY pulseid
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- The first table is named `api`
- The second table is named `rot`
- It is unclear what the last column should be.  I am adding `api` and `rot` which gives the correct values, but am not sure if that is what you want there.

Here is the query:

```
select
    api.pulseid,
    rot.Value as Rot,
    api.Value as API,
    rot.Value + api.Value as [Value]
from api
join rot on rot.pulseid = api.pulseid
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the downvotes are due to the lack of information surrounding the question, it comes across as if you haven't even tried it yourself. I took the question literally and can produce the results you requested with the following SQL:

```
SELECT
    Table_1.PulseID,
    Table_2.Value "rot",
    Table_1.Value "api",
    Table_2.Value
FROM
    Table_1
JOIN
    Table_2 ON
        Table_2.PulseID = Table_1.PulseID
        AND Table_2.Name = 'rot'
```